# Json decode when I iterate with forearch in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, foreach

So I have a table called Categories and this is his Seeder file:

```
SubCategories::create(array(
        'id' => '1',
        'category' => 'Books',
        'image' => '2.png',
        'subcategory' => '{"0":"Action","1":"Drama","3":"Romance","4":"Biography", "5":"Mystery"}'
    ));
```

What I want to do is to echo this in a view file:

```
@foreach($SubCategories as $SubCategory)
   <li>
     <figure>
       <div><img src="pictures/images/{{$SubCategory->image}}"></div>
         <figcaption>
             <h3>{{$SubCategory->category}}</h3>
             <br>
             <div class="cat_men">
                 <a href="#">{{$SubCategory->subcategory}}</a>
             </div>
         </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

This unfortunately echoes back at my site something like this:

> {"0":"Action","1":"Drama","3":"Romance","4":"Biography","5":"Mystery"}

I so when I try to use json_decode function with the following code:

```
@foreach(json_decode($SubCategory->subcategory,true) as $sub)
   <li> {{$sub->sub[0]}} </li>
@endforeach
```

I get the following error:

> ErrorException in de1a4fc568193a3fb9e08163f0b034f349f40fd8.php line 51:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

This is my controller:

```
public function getIndex() { 
   $SubCategories = SubCategories::all();
   return view('shop.index')->with('SubCategories',$SubCategories);
}
```

Anyone has any idea for this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
{{$sub}}
```

instead of

```
{{$sub->sub[0]}}
```

as you are already looping through the decoded JSON.

Comment: Well damn! That was easier than I thought...Thanks!